# Java 8 : How to update data in a linked list, where I need to pull the data of previous node to update data of current node

Tags: java, collections, java-8, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am currently stuck in java doubly linked list. I need to update the data of current node, based on the value of previous. It's going into a never ending loop if I try this :

```
 ListIterator<SegmentDTO> taskListIterator = segmentDTOLinkedList.listIterator(dataPosition);
            while (taskListIterator.hasNext())
            {
                SegmentDTO existingSegment = taskListIterator.next();
                existingSegment.setSequenceId(existingSegment.getSequenceId() + 1);

                if (taskListIterator.hasPrevious())
                {
                    SegmentDTO previousSegment = taskListIterator.previous();
                    LocalDateTime projectedStartDttm = existingSegment.getProjectedStartDttm();
                    LocalDateTime projectedEndDttm = existingSegment.getProjectedEndDttm();

                    long originalDifference = Duration.between(projectedStartDttm, projectedEndDttm).toHours();
                    LocalDateTime projectedEndDateTimeAfterNewStop = previousSegment.getProjectedEndDttm()
                            .plusHours(originalDifference);

                    existingSegment.setProjectedStartDttm(previousSegment.getProjectedEndDttm());
                    existingSegment.setProjectedEndDttm(projectedEndDateTimeAfterNewStop);
                }
            }
```

my hasNext() function is not coming out of while loop. It value is getting reset to previous, whenever I am trying to access previous data.

While loop end only if, I remove the call to previous(), but I need the data to update the current record based on previous. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is moving forward then back again through the `ListIterator` every time the while loop is executed. Call `taskListIterator.next()` in your if statement after you call `taskListIterator.previous()` to move it back forward.